# Fixed digits of all list values after decimal with f-strings or pretty print list with f string

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I have learnt numbers' output can be controlled well with f-string, is there any such magic with lists? I have a list of floats and want to print just 2 decimal point of each number.

an example of what I want although it is not a pretty solution (or is it the standard way of doing it these days?)

```
list = [1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9]
print(f"{[f'{val:.2f}' for val in list]}")
```

If there are also other pretty possibilities for printing list values, which I did not know of they are welcome. (e.g. numbers can have a fixed length, I would not know to ask for it)

Comment: Doesn't just `print([f'{val:.2f}' for val in list])` do the same thing for you?

Comment: Yes, but what you suggest is less general. Doesn't work with more text e.g. "here is my list {exp} and its length {len(lst)}"

Comment: Do you mean `print('here is my list:',[f'{val:.2f}' for val in lst],'and its length', len(lst))`?

Comment: This is a unique option to print. Think about logging.info for example. f strings are strings and can be used in many ways other than print().